# hitimes require error when running jekyll serve on windows 8.1

Tags: ruby, windows

I'm trying to run jekyll on my local machine running Windows 8.1, I've got Ruby installed and working but every time I run the `jekyll serve` command I get the error:

```
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- hitimes/hitimes (LoadError)
```

I've tried installing hitimes manually via `gem install hitimes` and it works fine, if I open up `irb` i can `require 'hitimes'` no problem it just doesn't seem to work for jekyll.

My `gem environment` is:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.5
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.2.1 (2015-02-26 patchlevel 85) [i386-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Ruby22/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby22/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: C:/Users/adam.laycock/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: C:/ProgramData
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
    - C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
    - C:/Users/adam.laycock/.gem/ruby/2.2.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
    - :update_sources => true
    - :verbose => true
    - :backtrace => false
    - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
    - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
    - C:\RubyDevKit\bin
    - C:\RubyDevKit\mingw\bin
    - C:\windows\system32
    - C:\windows
    - C:\windows\System32\Wbem
    - C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
    - C:\Program Files\nodejs\
    - C:\Users\adam.laycock\AppData\Roaming\npm
    - C:\Users\adam.laycock\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_c2ba306e536fdf878271f7fe636a147ff37326ad\cmd
    - C:\Users\adam.laycock\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_c2ba306e536fdf878271f7fe636a147ff37326ad\bin
    - C:\Users\adam.laycock\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_c2ba306e536fdf878271f7fe636a147ff37326ad\mingw\bin
    - C:\Users\adam.laycock\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\O3WGNDW8.VMM\C2M3657K.JNR\gith..tion_317444273a93ac29_0002.000a_7c768ac46c12be54
    - C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
    - C:\Ruby22\Bin
```

`jekyll -v` returns 2.5.3

Comment: In such cases, it would have been a good idea to raise this problem on their bug tracker. That way, this issue might have a chance to be fixed. I took the liberty of adding the problem: https://github.com/copiousfreetime/hitimes/issues/39

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It probably has to do with some breaking ABI changes in Ruby 2.2 and `hitimes-1.2.2-x86-mingw32` doesn't include the fat binary for it Ruby 2.2.

The fix is to just uninstall and re-install it and use `--platform ruby` when installing.

So do this:

```
gem uni hitimes

**Remove ALL versions**

gem ins hitimes -v 1.2.1 --platform ruby
```

That will recompile `hitimes` that is compatible with Ruby 2.2.

**Edit**: As [*copiousfreetime* mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28985481/hitimes-require-error-when-running-jekyll-serve-on-windows-8-1/28998745?noredirect=1#comment47157205_28998745), the [RubyInstaller DevKit](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit#2-download-files) is required to compile binary *rubygems*

Versions `1.2.3` and above of `hitimes` should contain fat binaries for `Ruby 2.2.X` releases. *[Thanks copiousfreetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28985481/hitimes-require-error-when-running-jekyll-serve-on-windows-8-1/28998745?noredirect=1#comment52951657_28998745)*

Comment: This will only work if you have the windows ruby DevKit installed. Hitimes uses a C extension and requires a compiler to build for source.

Comment: For me it worked with `gem ins hitimes -v 1.2.2 --platform ruby`

Comment: I've released version 1.2.3 of hitimes which includes a fatbinary version for windows so the devkit is not longer necessary for hitimes installation on windows.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE (2015-09-13)** Hitimes version 1.2.3 is released which solves this issue.

This is somewhat expected, since hitimes v1.2.2 was released in January, and the first Ruby 2.2 release for Windows was release 1 month ago on March 6. I haven't had a chance to build hitimes for Windows with Ruby 2.2 fat binaries yet.  I have opened up an issue for hitimes to release a new fat binary of hitimes that includes support for Ruby 2.2 -- https://github.com/copiousfreetime/hitimes/issues/40